# How to control amount of checkpoint kept by tensorflow estimator?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I've noticed that the new Estimator API automatically saves checkpoints during the training and automatically restarts from the last checkpoint when training was interrupted. Unfortunately, it seems it only keeps the last 5 checkpoints.

Do you know how to control the number of checkpoints that are kept during the training?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tensorflow [tf.estimator.Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) takes `config` as an optional argument, which can be a [tf.estimator.RunConfig](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/RunConfig) object to configure runtime settings.You can achieve this as follows:

```py
# Change maximum number checkpoints to 25
run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig()
run_config = run_config.replace(keep_checkpoint_max=25)

# Build your estimator
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn,
                                   model_dir=job_dir,
                                   config=run_config,
                                   params=None)
```

`config` parameter is available in all classes (`DNNClassifier`, `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier`, `LinearClassifier`, etc.) that extend `estimator.Estimator`.

Comment: Exactly the info I needed, and the RunConfig has additional params like `save_checkpoints_secs` and `save_checkpoints_steps`, perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As a side note I would like to add that in TensorfFlow2 the situation is a little bit simpler. To keep a certain number of checkpoint files you can modify the `model_main_tf2.py` source code. First you can add and define an integer flag as

```
# Keep last 25 checkpoints
flags.DEFINE_integer('checkpoint_max_to_keep', 25,
                     'Integer defining how many checkpoint files to keep.')
```

Then use this pre-defined value in a call to `model_lib_v2.train_loop`:

```
# Ensure training loop keeps last 25 checkpoints
model_lib_v2.train_loop(...,
                        checkpoint_max_to_keep=FLAGS.checkpoint_max_to_keep,
                        ...)
```

The symbol `...` above denotes other options to `model_lib_v2.train_loop`.